# Inserting variables into innerHTML

Tags: javascript, function, variables, html-table

I'm trying to create a table that appears in id="here".

The problem is I need to put "var i" inside of the table heading (th).

When executed the table does not appear - I assume this is because the string breaks when I add in "var i".

Are there any ways around this? Is there a known method of inserting variables into tables like this?

Any/All help is appreciated :)

```
<p id="here"></p>
<button type="button" onclick="test();"></button>

<script>

var i = Dogs;
function test() {document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = 
"<table><tr><th>" + i + "</th></tr></table>";}

</script>
```

Comment: Dogs isn't in quotes, so it's not a string. Do you see any console errors?

Comment: Because you need to wrap the string with either single or double quotes. `var i = "Dogs";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add quotes to Dogs. String literals must have quotes.

```js
var i = "Dogs";
function test() {document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = 
"<table><tr><th>" + i + "</th></tr></table>";}
```

```html
<p id="here"></p>
<button type="button" onclick="test();">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use append child instead:

```
var table = document. createElement("table")
document.getElementById("hello").appendChild(table)
```

...so on so forth